# Extract VSCode Debugging icons to PNG file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

[image]

In Visual Stuio Code Debugging, there are 6 icons ,

How to get the raw png Image of those icons?

I tried open inspector but have no clue how to do this

(BecauseI want to print some those icons and glue to my keyboard)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-codicons/tree/main/src/icons

Comment: what is wrong with the good old `Print Screen` (Screen capture) (Snipping Tool)

Comment: @rioV8 the good old print screen cant get the clearer raw image

Comment: they are SVG images, zoom-in the GUI and you get a big image

Comment: @rioV8 It have background